# Confused About How to insert xml value into database

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, xml

I am dealing with xml files and I have found an example [here](http://csharp.net-informations.com/xml/xml-to-database.htm).I have changed connection string  and created a table named MyProducts then I have manually  located my Product.xml files inside App_Data folder.When i run my program get this  execption

> Invalid object name 'Product'.

So in the debug mode I have noticed that myxml variable is null What am i doing wrong

```
              protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string connetionString = null;
        SqlConnection connection;
        SqlCommand command ;
        SqlDataAdapter adpter = new SqlDataAdapter();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        XmlReader xmlFile ;
        string sql = null;

        int product_ID = 0;
        string Product_Name = null;
        double product_Price = 0;

        connetionString = "Data Source=.\\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=Northwind;Integrated Security=sspi";

        connection = new SqlConnection(connetionString);


        xmlFile = XmlReader.Create(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Product.xml"), new XmlReaderSettings());
        ds.ReadXml(xmlFile);
        int i = 0;
        connection.Open();
        for (i = 0; i <= ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            product_ID = Convert.ToInt32(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[0]);
            Product_Name = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[1].ToString();
            product_Price = Convert.ToDouble(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[2]);
            sql = "insert into Product values(" + product_ID + ",'" + Product_Name + "'," + product_Price + ")";
            command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
            adpter.InsertCommand = command;
            adpter.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        connection.Close();
        Label1.Text = "ok";

    }
```

Comment: you table called MyProducts and you're trying to insert into Product

Comment: Thank you Roman  I think I must get some sleep

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I've said in comments, you've just misspelled your table name - you table called MyProducts and you're trying to insert into Product

```
insert into MyProducts ...
```